# No puedo iniciar sesión usando cookies con react y cognito

Tags: reactjs, aws, cookies, cognito, amplify

Estoy cambiando donde se guardan las credenciales de cognito, ahorita se estaban guardando en localstorage pero yo quiero que se guarden en las cookies, por lo que configure mi cognido de la siguiente forma:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    cookieStorage: {
      domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMINION,
      path: process.env.REACT_APP_PATH,
      secure: false,
      expires: 365
    },
    oauth: {
      domain: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
      scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_SIGNIN,
      redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_SIGNOUT,
      responseType: 'code'
    }
  }
});
```

Ahora en mi .env.development tiene lo siguiente:

```
REACT_APP_DOMINION=localhost:3000
REACT_APP_PATH=/
REACT_APP_SIGNIN=http://localhost:3000/dashboard/
REACT_APP_SIGNOUT=http://localhost:3000/login/
...
```

Ahora cuando hago inicio de sesión por medio de google, me muestra lo siguiente en la consola (no puedo subir imagenes):

```
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 14
Cookie “amplify-redirected-from-hosted-ui” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “amplify-polling-started” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “amplify-redirected-from-hosted-ui” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “amplify-polling-started” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
XHRPOST
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
[HTTP/2 400  295ms]
```

Al verificar la respuestas del error 400, me muestra lo siguiente: `error: "invalid_grant"` y despues tambien en la consola muestra lo siguiente:

```
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxx.google_xxxxxxxxxx.userData” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxxxxx.google_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.idToken” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxx.google_xxxxxxxxxx.accessToken” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxx.google_xxxxxxxxxx.refreshToken” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxx.google_xxxxxxxxxx.clockDrift” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
Cookie “CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxxx.LastAuthUser” has been rejected for invalid domain. js.cookie.js:98
```

Por lo que no estoy segurdo si me falta hacer una configuración mas o tendria que cambiar algo?

Estoy usando:

- react: 17.0.2
- aws-amplify: 5.0.4
- NodeJS: 14